# Using XQuartz for communicating to the Centos server using local graphical user interface

Tags: macos, xquartz

I wonder how to use XQuartz to communicate with the Centos server through a *local* graphical user interface on my Mac? I did the following steps so far, and the result so far is just connect to the server through terminal.

- Server side:

  1. Installed gdm on the server.
  2. Switched run level to 5.
- Client side:

  1. Installed XQuartz on my Mac OS 10.8.
  2. On Terminal: ssh X root.website.com.

**Update**

After doing what @onik suggested (using the xterm instead of terminal, created a new user other than root, and entered the command gnome-session), I get the following warnings before xterm halts:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to switch to runlevel 5, this only means that the server boots into the GUI, not that it's useable. You can use runlevel 3 and launch remote X sessions.

Furthermore, you'll have to use `xterm` to start the SSH session, not Terminal.app. If you run XQuartz it should open it by default. Then run `ssh -X root.website.com` to open the session and from this session you can launch the needed applications. If you need the entire desktop, run `gnome-session &` or your desired VM.

Note that you need to have `X11Forwarding yes` in your `/etc/ssh/sshd.conf`.

Comment: This is a bug in at least Ubuntu, you need to set the right permissions to the dbus files under your user's home. SSH to the server and run `sudo chown -R <youruser>:<yourgroup> ~/.dbus` and it should be fixed. More details [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gconf/+bug/367169).

Comment: cerated the new user and the problem still exist (updated the question with the list of warnings).